# How to print mongoose find() array docs in console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use `mongodb` with `node.js` using `Mongoose ODM`.

I've written some sample code which is given below:

**Sample Code -**

```
/*!
 * mongoose.js
 * 
 * Getting Started
 */ 

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/trymongo').connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connected to database");  // we're connected!
  
  // create schemas
  var SubjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    teacher: {
        type: String
    }
  },
  {
    collection: 'subjects'
  });

  // create a model
  var Subject = mongoose.model('Subject', SubjectSchema);
  
  var arr = [{ name: 'Computer Programming', teacher: 'M. Swaminathan' }, { name: 'History' }];
  Subject.insertMany(arr, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    
    console.log('Multiple subjects created!');

    // get all the subjects
    Subject.find({}, function(err, subjects) {
        if (err) throw err;
                
        console.log(subjects);
    });
  });
});
```

I want to print subjects in console using `console.log()` returned by mongoose model but it only prints like this -

```
[ [object Object], [object Object] ]
```

I've also tried with `console.dir()` but result is same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(subjects, null, 4))`

More about [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Or `console.log('%j', subjects)` if you're okay with unindented JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started learning Mongoose and found this question while facing the same problem now over 7 years after it was originally posted. I was finally able to figure out how to print the docs queried by a .find() to terminal for Mongoose version 7.0, which probably isn't helpful in regards to the original post, but I figured I would share for the benefit of anyone stumbling upon this question onwards of 2023.

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.xxxxxxx.mongodb.net/fruitDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(uri);

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  key: value,
  key: value
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

Fruit.find({}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
}).finally(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

You need to resolve the promise returned by the .find() call --- if you try to console.log() the result before it's resolved then it will print the query object to the terminal. If you console.log() the result inside an anonymous function after appending .then() you ensure that the .find() promise has been resolved before proceeding and you print the resulting array of doc objects as intended.

I apologize if anything I've said is outright wrong, I do not have very much experience coding yet.

Answer (score 0):

just in case for those who are struggling to console log only the names of  the fruits :

```
  Fruit.find()
  .then((fruits) => {
    fruits.forEach((fruits) => {
      console.log('Names of fruits:', fruits.name);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error retrieving documents:', error);
  }).finally(()=> {
    mongoose.connection.close();
  });
```